# Rails reverse scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have

```
 scope :delivered, where(:status => Status::DELIVERED)
 SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."status" IN ('Pending', 'Partially Prepared')
```

Now I want to add new scope to get all except delivered orders.

```
 scope :not_delivered, where(:status != Status::DELIVERED)
 SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE ('t')
```

How to get a reverse scope?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a string condition. `scope :not_delivered, where('status NOT ?', Status::DELIVERED)`.

Not confident about the syntax, I don't do SQL often. But you should get the idea.

Comment: Should be `scope :not_delivered, where('status!=?', Status::DELIVERED)`